# VBA CountA / countif with addition

Tags: vba, function, loops, excel

hi Guys just quick question. I am trying to do a **Counta / Countif formula** in VBA excel.  The code I'm working with is the following.

```
Sub To_open
  Dim x as Range 
  x  =COUNTA('Tier 2'!C2:C1000)+COUNTA('Tier 3'!C2:C1000)+COUNTA('Tier 4'!C2:C1000)+COUNTA('Tier 5'!C2:C1000)

  If x = 0 then 
    msgbox " No impact "
  End If   
End sub
```

The code is suppose to  **count and add the rows in coloumn C with values, in the the 4 sheets** and if it **equals zero** then show the message box.

Comment: Where i have put " X=" , the formula is an excel formula. i am trying to convert it to VBA language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using the Evaluate function:

```
Sub To_open()
  Dim n             As Long

  n = Evaluate("COUNTA('Tier 2'!C2:C1000) + " & _
               "COUNTA('Tier 3'!C2:C1000) + " & _
               "COUNTA('Tier 4'!C2:C1000) + " & _
               "COUNTA('Tier 5'!C2:C1000)")
  MsgBox n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 x =Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTA('Tier 2'!C2:C1000)+COUNTA('Tier 3'!C2:C1000)+COUNTA('Tier 4'!C2:C1000)+COUNTA('Tier 5'!C2:C1000))
```